How can I test Apache Spark on Iceberg with a JDBC Catalog?
In the past, I have tested Apache Spark using the Hive driver in J-Meter.  I'm trying to run some benchmarks on it now against Trino and I'm using J-Meter.  Testing Trino is easy with their JDBC driver.  Since I'm not using Hive for my metastore, how do I test SQL on Apache Spark for Iceberg tables using the JDBC catalog (Postgres).
I'm trying to test a cohort of 10 SQL queries via J-Meter at concurrency scales of X for multiple SQL engines (Trino & Spark).

If you have a JDBC URL and credentials you can simulate multiple/concurrent SQL queries using JMeter.

Download PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
Drop it under JMeter Classpath
Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
Add JDBC Connection Configuration and provide your database URL, credentials and other parameters if neeeded
Add JDBC Request sampler and put your query there

More information:

Building a Database Test Plan
Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter

